# array there are three numbers of in a row

Tags: java, arrays

How to returns true if at least somewhere in the array there are three numbers of in a row in ascending order, false if not

```
public static boolean tripleUp(int[] array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if(array[i] < array[i + 1] && array[i + 1] == array[i] + 1){
            count++;
            if(count < 2){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

tripleUp([1, 4, 5, 6, 2]) → true
tripleUp([1, 2, 3]) → true
tripleUp([1, 2, 4]) → false
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward.

```
public static boolean tripleUp(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 2; ++i) {
        if (array[i+1] == array[i] + 1 && array[i+2] == array[i] + 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
static boolean inSeq(int[] arr, int n)
{
  if(arr == null || arr.length < n) return false;

  if(n <= 1) return true;

  for(int i=1, j=0; i <= arr.length; i++)
  {
    if(i == arr.length || arr[i] == arr[i-1]+1)
    {
      if(i - j == n) return true;
    }
    else
    {
      j = i;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int[][] tests = {
      {1, 4, 5, 6, 2},
      {1, 2, 3},
      {1, 2, 4}
  };

  for(int[] test : tests)
    System.out.printf("%s : %b\n", Arrays.toString(test), inSeq(test, 3));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2] : true
[1, 2, 3] : true
[1, 2, 4] : false
```

Comment: Change the 5 to a 3 in your first test and the 2 to a 3 in the last and see what happens.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Thanks for catching that. Fixed now. Better to use offset of indices than counts.